# Proving measurability of a function

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

I am interested in linking the classical measure theoretic approach with the Daniell approach. So I am working with the textbook by Alan J. Weir called "General Integration and Measure". I am coming up with a problem understanding the proof of the Extension theorem stated on page 97 in the book. Weir says here in the second part of the proof that the set $S$ belongs to the ring $\mathcal{R}_0$ constructed before (I could understood and proofed this.) Then he gives the equation $\min(\chi_E,\phi)=\min(\chi_{E\cap S},\phi)$, which I also proofed checking the different cases. But now there is the problem: He argues, that the $\min$-function described before belongs to $L(\mathcal{R}_0)$ - which are the simple functions on $\mathcal{R}_0$ - and hence $\chi_E$ is a measurable function (in terms of the Daniell integral constructed on the page before). I can't see why these two statements are true. And the next question would be, why do I have to proof the measurability, isn't it directly true, because $\chi_E$ is a simple function?
Does anyone has an idea? I would be very happy! Thank you.

Comment: I solved the first problem, to show the measurability you can use the definition (the mid-function). The only thing remaining to prove is the fact that $\min(\chi_{E\cap S},\phi)$ belongs to $L(\mathcal{R}_0)$...

Comment: The second question could be solved by the fact that $\mu(E\cap S)≤ \mu(S)$.